# Did I understand right how to build robust php backends with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

Most of you should know that 'famous' article about "[Writing Robust PHP Backends with Zend Framework](http://www.angryobjects.com/2009/03/30/writing-robust-php-backends-with-zend-framework/)"
After an insteresting reading, i decided to give it a try, since i couldn't be able to find the gold solution to handle my datas.

Then, i tried to write kind of a skeleton, to have a concrete example.

But some points looks weird for me. But I'll tell more about this later.

I removed some code to be clearer.
Here is the code :

```
    // Kind of stdClass. the User Domain Object
    // Nothing more to say, it's just about to have a User object
    // I guess we could do here some business logic like the username should
    // be only alpha, etc..

    class User
    {
        $_data = array('userId', 'userName');
        public function __construct($data = null)
        {
            $this->populate($data);
        }
        
        public function populate($data = null)
        {
            if ( is_object ($data) )
            {
                $data = (array) $data;
            }
        
            if ( ! is_array($data) )
            {
                throw new Exception ('Data must be an array or an object');
            }
            
            foreach ($data as $property => $value)
            {
                $this->$property = $value;
            }
        }
        
        public function toArray()
        {
            return $this->_data;
        }
    }
    
   // The UserTable extends Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract or Zend_Db_Table
   // Here we do things like fetch, add, update, etc...
   // Validating the data depending on the persistent layers which is the db :
   // respect the data types and formats.

   class UserTable extends Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
    {
        public function __construct ($options)
        {
            parent::__construct($options);
        }
        
        public function validateUser($user)
        {
            if ( null == $user->name || len($user->name) >= 30 || len($user->name) <= 0 )
            {
                throw new Zend_Db_Exception ('Username must be between  0 and 30 chars and must not be null');
            } 
            
            $user->name = $this->quote($user->name);
            
            return $user;        
        }
        
        public function createUser(User $user)
        {
            $user = $this->validateUser($user);
            
            $user = $user->toArray();
            
            try
            {
                $this->insert('Users', $user);
                $user->id $this->lastInsertId('Users');
                
            } catch (Zend_Db_Expection $e) {
                echo 'Error while creating user :', $e->getMessage();
            }
            
            return $user;
        }
        
        public function updateUser(User $user)
        {
            $user = $this->validateUser($user);
            
            $user = $user->toArray();
        
            if (null == $user->id)
            {
                throw new Exception ('User must have an userId to be updated');
            }
            
            try
            {
                $this->update('Users', $user, 'userId = ' . $user->id);
                
            } catch (Zend_Db_Expection $e) {
                echo 'Error while updating user :', $e->getMessage();
            }
            
            return $user;
        }
    }

    // the UserService will be used like an API from the Controller
    // Let says that our adapters must implements an interface for our Service
    // be able to work.
    // It overrides the method provided by the adapter without knowledge of
    // the data is stored. You can then provide another adapter 
    // than DB (like webservice, xml, etc...)
    // But then, if the adapter implements an interface, why should I use 
    // a Service Layer ? Maybe i didn't understand the Service Layer Concept.

    class UserService
    {
        $_adapter = null;
        
        public function __construct($adapter = null)
        {
            $this->setAdapter($adapter);
        }
        
        public function setAdapter($adapter = null)
        {
            $this->_adapter = $adaper;
        }
        
        public function getUserById($id = 0)
        {
            $this->getAdapter()->getUserById($id);
        }
        
        public function save(User $user)
        {
            if (null != $user->id)
            {
                $this->getAdapter()->createUser($user);
            } else {
                $this->getAdapter()->updateUser($user);
            }
        }
        
        // proxy method to the PostService
        // let's say that we have getPostsByUser($userId) method within the 
        // PostService class
        // Btw, Maybe we should find a better way to initialize the adapter,
        // to let it less dependent.
        
        public function getPosts(User $user)
        {
            $postService = new PostService(new PostTable());
            return $postService->getPostsByUser($user->id);
        }
    }
    
    

    // The use in a controller is pretty easy, and the controller, just do 
    // what it should in an MVC architecture.
    // get the data from the model, pass it to the view.

    class UserController
    {
        protected $user = null;
        
        public function init()
        {
            // get the user object from the session
        }
        public function postsAction()
        {
            $userService = new UserService(new UserTable());
            
            $this->view->posts = $userService->getPostsByUser($user->id);
            
        }
    }
```

So the final question is, Did I understand the concept ? or Did i make some mistakes implementing it ?

*P.S. : the tags autocompletion didn't work anymore so i wasn't able to provide the right tags.*

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at the [Zend_Db_Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html). It would spare you create the UserTable class.

Also your controller doesn't extend Zend_Controller_Action how comes.

Last things you would probably want to use Zend_From or Zend_Validate to validate your model.

I thing your implementation is not so bad but this article seems to be old to me.

Comment: You are right about Zend_Db_Table, but i like to be able to make my own Select statements with joins, etc.. but I will, promess.
I just forgot to extends the controller but it actually does.
You are right about Zend_Form & Zend_Validate, but the forms will actually fit into a UserForm class which will have no relation except with the Service Layer. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: You can do joins with Zend_Db_table just you have to disable integrity  checks. Hope you get a great learning curve with ZF. I am using it since 2 month and I really love it, I have just rediscovered PHP.